# Flutter: Animate a widget on removal from the widget tree, or during the end of it's lifecycle?

Tags: animation, flutter, widget, lifecycle

I have a GridView which shows custom widgets for the items in the grid.  These items have an animation that scale their size from 0 to 100% when they appear in the grid, using an AnimationController.forward() command.

My hope is, that when  the list of items in the grid changes and one of these items is no longer in the list, I'd like to reverse the animation before the widget is removed from the tree, to animate it's removal from the grid.

I tried doing a AnimationController.reverse() in the dispose method of the widget, but that doesn't appear to work.

Is there any way to animate a widget during the end of it's lifecycle?

Comment: I think you can't animate it on dispose because it's too late and widget is already being removed. You need to start removal animation first and set a callback to remove a widget from the tree after the animation is complete

Comment: The problem is, the list provided to the GridView is dynamic, and unless I maintain a list of all items that are in the grid and compare it to the new list I received from the server, I'm not sure how I'd know that the item was 'leaving' before it was gone?  That may ultimately be what I need to do to accomplish what I'm after.  Thanks

Comment: I recommend you looking into _AnimatedSwitcher_ widget. Learn how it works, maybe you'll get an idea how to implement such a thing. Or you can just use AnimatedSwitcher to animate whole grid.

Comment: found any solutions?

Comment: I have a vague idea that you can use ScrollController and call reverse() at the scroll you want. Based on widget size. Needs a bit of testing though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this pub https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/auto_animated.
You can combine your custom animation with this pub and being able to reach the desired behaviour.

```
// With predefined options
LiveGrid.options(
  options: options,

  // Like GridView.builder, but also includes animation property
  itemBuilder: buildAnimatedItem,

  // Other properties correspond to the `ListView.builder` / `ListView.separated` widget
  itemCount: itemsCount,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 3,
    crossAxisSpacing: 16,
    mainAxisSpacing: 16,
  ),
);
```

**buildAnimatedItem** can be your custom animation, you can define like this:

```
Widget buildAnimatedItem(
  BuildContext context,
  int index,
  Animation<double> animation,
) =>
  // For example wrap with fade transition
  FadeTransition(
    opacity: Tween<double>(
      begin: 0,
      end: 1,
    ).animate(animation),
    // And slide transition
    child: SlideTransition(
      position: Tween<Offset>(
        begin: Offset(0, -0.1),
        end: Offset.zero,
      ).animate(animation),
      // Paste you Widget
      child: YouWidgetHere(),
    ),
  );
```

Take a look at the pub Readme is pretty clear